# Kubernetes dashboard not allowing to login

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to kubernets and trying to acess dashboard using the tokens, no reposnse in the UI

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
EOF
```

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
EOF
```

could you please help here?

Regards
Arvind

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes is complex, and used to change way too quickly. With that consideration, I deployed a small Kubernetes cluster early last year, and deployed and used the dashboard on it following the tips in the dashboard documentation here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/tree/master/docs

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what exactly wen't bad, maybe you did not setup proxy to access the UI.
Maybe some `pods` are not working, you can check that by `$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system`
Also make sure the token is present 
`$ kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}')`

The process of setting up sample user is explained [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md).

I would recommend using something that's up to date, meaning Dashboard 2.0.
You can see the whole installation process [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard).

> To deploy Dashboard, execute following command:
>
> `$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-rc5/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml`
>
> To access Dashboard from your local workstation you must create a secure channel to your Kubernetes cluster. Run the following command:
>
> `$ kubectl proxy`
>
> Now access Dashboard at:
>
> [`http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/`](http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/).

Also I do not recommend deploying anything inside kube-system namespace, it's better to create a new namespaces to play to.